# Unable to get browser cookies using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to get browser cookies through Java Script using document.cookie. When i run my code on different-2 machines, then i am unable to get browser cookies every time.

I checked into browser's developer tool under resource tab, cookies are available there. But unable to get it every time. I mean to say that on one machine i am able to get it, on another machine, i am not able to get.

When i debug my code, i found that document.cookie is returning me a blank string on another machine, although cookies are available in browser.

I am using google chrome with latest version. So i think, there should not be any issues with browser because i can see cookies are available in browsers.

Can someone please help me find that what could be reason for this issue ?

`var x = document.cookie;`

Comment: Please share the code you're using to obtain the cookies.

Comment: `document.cookies() method` - no such method exists, you want `document.cookie` property

Comment: also, some cookies are not available to javascript, i.e. **httponly** cookies

Comment: I agree. It's a typo error which i made correct. I have also added code snippet. Also let me know how to identify httponly cookies ?

Comment: Are you using the same url to load the page on both machines or perhaps a domain on one and an IP on another?

Comment: I got the issue. It's a httponly cookies and that's why i am not able to get those cookies. Thanks to Jaromanda X.